# Solr - multiple condition query

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I'm using Solr and Conceptnet to try and find the relation between two concepts. 
 So, let's say we want to check if Hamburg is a city. My query looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*%28start:%28/c/en/hamburg%29%20AND%20end:%28/c/en/city%29%29%20AND%20rel:%28/r/IsA%29&fl=start,end,rel
```

The condition for the end term or the relation are completly ignored.
What am I doing wrong here? Any ideas?

Thanks :)

**Update**
Changed the Solr config to use the WhitespaceTokenizer for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided your schema.xml so here is my best guess. If `start`, `end` and `rel` are string fields, the following query should work:

```
q=start:"/c/en/hamburg" AND end:"/c/en/city" AND rel:"/r/IsA"&fl=start,end,rel
```

Comment: I had to use the Whitespace Tokenizer to make it work, but that's exactly the query I needed. Thanks!